# How to get the values ​​of the probability density of a given data using R? The goal is to get the values of the function not the graph

Tags: r, time-series, density-function

The problem is the following:
If I have data from 2002 to 2005 of operational risk then I want to get the value of density associated with this.

```
X # is the data from 2002 to 2005, X takes values [-200,200] 
density(X) # the density of X
```

The question is how to get the values of this density?

For example, if I take any value X0 in X. say 109, then how to get this value?

Comment: Your question is a a bit confusing. Can you post some sample data and try to clarify what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: If your question is to retrieve the values of the density, then you might try something like: `density(x)$y` and `density(x)$x`.

Comment: @COOLSerdash has answered your question (although that will not work for an arbitrary input value - only the ones used to build the kernel density estimate) but I'd say this is off topic and is better suited for stackoverflow...

Comment: One Example : if X <- rnorm(4)  the the density is density(X) and we can get any values of the density using dnorm(X0), but if we consider any data set Z discrete the we have the density  density(Z) so how to get the value of the density of Z0 in Z?

Comment: To know the density can be calculated using `dnorm`, you'd have to know a priori that the data are normally distributed (and this has nothing to do with your call to `density`). If you're asking how to evaluate a kernel density estimate at an arbitrary point, then [my answer to the migrated version of this question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365342/how-to-get-the-values-of-the-probability-density-of-a-given-data-using-r-the/18365680#18365680) gives one approach. The question has since been closed there due to perceived lack of clarity in the problem statement.

Comment: Marco thank you very much, your answer helped me a lot